# .html and .text not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wanted to display some integer values in the html from javascript but unfortunately both .html and .text is not working

here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".total").text("<?php  echo $row_price['product_price'] + $economy; ?>");
    $('input:radio[name="shipping_type"]').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == "economy"){
        $(".total").text("<?php  echo $row_price['product_price'] + $economy; ?>");
        }else{

        $(".total").text("<?php  echo $row_price['product_price'] + $fast; ?>")

        }
    });

</script>
```

By checking the source code value is successfully coming in the .text() function. no error is displaying on the console as well
html

```
 <tr>
<td class='radio-container'>
<input checked="checked" id="shipping_type_economy" name="shipping_type" type="radio" value="economy" />
</td>
<td><label for="shipping_type_domestic">Economy</label></td>
<td class='right'>
<span class="economy">10.20$</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='radio-container'>
<input id="shipping_type_fast" name="shipping_type" type="radio" value="fast" />
</td>
<td><label for="shipping_type__fast">Fast</label></td>
<td class='right'>
<span class="fast">20.00$</span>
</td>
</tr>
  <tr><td>TOTAL</td>
    <td class="right" id="total"><span class="total"><span/></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Is the PHP part running on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct,just wrap your Jquery Code inside [**$(document).ready(function(){..})**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block as shown below :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Jquery Code
});
```

Comment: well If I was missing this It should have to show me the error on the console but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jQuery syntax, which requires you to have the jQuery library included. jQuery is a library on top of javascript. http://jquery.com/, besides that, the code needs to be wrapped in a doc ready statement.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

....your code

});
</script>
```